# Start .exe files from command line windows from other directories

Tags: firefox, exe, lazarus

When I start firefox from command line, i does not matter in which directory I am. When I want to start for example lazarus i need to go to directory where file lazarus.exe is located.

Why can I start firefox.exe from everywhere and some other .exe files i must go to right directory

```
C:\Users\Seda> start firefox.exe       // run perfectly
C:\Users\Seda> start lazarus.exe       // can not find exe file
C:\Users\Seda> cd ..
C:\Users> cd ..
C:\>cd Lazarus
C:\Lazarus> start lazarus.exe // .exe file started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Firefox does is to add the path to its executable to the "[App Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#appPaths)" subkey, which is the preferred solution against modifying the 'path' environment variable. To make the same for lazarus, you can add a

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\lazarus.exe
```

key having the `(Default)` value of the path to the executable, e.g.: `X\...\lazarus.exe`

To have an effect on all users, you can use the machine counterpart of course

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#app_exe) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You must setup the path in the Windows environment. quick google got me this link - http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your firefox has been added to the environment variable which is why you can start it anywhere without specifying the full path

check under Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables